# Docker plugins for eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, docker, dockerfile

I have a problem with Dockerfiles on eclipse. I am using eclipse neon and I would like to get rid of error: Unknown instruction: ARG.

It seems to be described in this issue:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496782

I tried to upgrade eclipse to newest version (Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3))
I tried to upgrade all plugins that have something to do with docker; especially the one mentioned in link above. 
I tried remove all those plugins. 
I started eclipse with clean option.
Now I do not have any editor related to Dockerfiles, but error still exists!

It is little bit frustrating. Can someone suggest what else should be upgraded/removed?

Comment: The newest version is Oxygen.2: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Docker Tooling in eclipse.In  Help > Install New Softwar , then give below repo url.

```
http://download.eclipse.org/release/neon
```

And then select Docker Tooling under Genral Purpose Tools